# Are long running questions discouraged on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, support

I know that Stack Overflow is a Q&A site and not a discussion forum, but does that necessarily imply that questions which cannot be answered right away will be closed?

I mean it may so happen that a question can be answered more effectively in the future (maybe once more research has been done on the topic), but that does not necessarily mean that it cannot have a satisfactory answer now. Say it is obvious that the question cannot be correctly answered entirely right way, will Stack Overflow not entertain it? If not, why?

Comment: Is this just a theoretical issue, or do you have any real life examples?

Comment: Well I just got one of my questions closed and the reason given was that the question could take a long time to answer. So I just got curious.

Comment: There's a difference between something that will take a long time to answer and something that will require a lot of discussion to answer. I can't see a problem with the former, but the latter should be closed.

Comment: No, Aki, that is not what [Kev was saying](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8353666/application-causing-phone-to-heat-up) in the comments of that question. He was referring to the list being endless in length, not in time.

Comment: @Arjan  By the list being endless do you mean that the answer would be too long or that I have crammed too many different questions in one question? If it is the second case I totally agree with Kev closing the question, but if it was the first case, he could have simply answered the question, cited a few examples, mentioned that there could be too many factors, maybe shared a link which would point me in the right direction.

Comment: In one of his comments Kev says -- "Well you're effectively asking for a list of all the things that might make your app warm up a handset. That could go on forever.", which actually led me to believe that he thought that either the answer to the question would be too long or it could not be correctly / satisfactorily answered right away. My apologies if I misunderstood him.

Comment: @Arjan Anyway, I did not post this question to discuss or reason why Kev closed my question. I beleive my question was pretty straight forward, does StackOverflow entertain question which cannot be correctly / satisfactorily answered right away, which might take a bit of discussion. If not, why?

Comment: @ChrisF Why should questions which require discussion be closed? StackOverflow is a place where people having same interest come together. It is entirely possible that by discussing we can have better answers. Why should we discourage discussions?

Comment: Because Stack Overflow is not a discussion site. It's a **Question and Answer** site.

Comment: @ChrisF Agreed. But you do agree that discussions lead to better answers? In StackOverflow most of the discussion takes place through comments (maybe chat). I believe we are **discussing** right now. Eventually you have to discuss to solve most questions, sometimes to better understand the question, sometimes to come up with the right answer.

Comment: Notice I said **a lot** of discussion. Some discussion is inevitable and that's what comments and chat are for. **Extended** discussion on the site isn't productive.

Comment: Why would say it is not productive? Going through discussions does enable a person to better understand the reason behind the answer being correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I posted this question immediately after Kev my closed question, it wasn't my intention to discuss the reason why Kev closed **my question**. It was more sort a general wondering. People have answered my question, mostly in the form of comments. So I figured that I would go and post the answer myself. I hope that is acceptable.

Quoting ChrisF,

> Stack Overflow is not a discussion site. It's a Question and Answer site.
>
> Notice I said a lot of discussion. Some discussion is inevitable and that's what comments and chat are for. Extended discussion on the site isn't productive.

That was pretty much it. Moreover I found this [section in the faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) which explained the issue more clearly.

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

It was the "push other questions off the front page" that answers my question. Other than that I couldn't find many reasons for discussions not being productive.

Answer (score 2):

Based on what Kev stated in his comment, I've changed the close reason to one that more closely aligns with his thinking.  The new close reason is **Not Constructive**:

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers
>   to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this
>   question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or
>   extended discussion.

Hopefully that clears things up a bit.